# How to know the package or module name from import statement in Python?

Tags: python, pip

I have a python file and the developer of that code has left the organization. When I run the code I get the following error.

> import dataAnalysis as DV ModuleNotFoundError: No module named
>   'dataAnalysis'

I provide below the brief snippet of the python file "main.py" below.

```
import dataAnalysis as DV

def performCheck():
    ... other code
    ... other code
    i = DV.addGraph( pathplus)
```

Here my question is , how to know the actual module or package name of "dataAnalysis" from the above import statement so that I can make "pip install ". However, I tried to install DataAnalysis module, still it does not work.

Is there any way to get the module or package name to install from the import statement in python ?

Comment: It might have been a local package the guy implemented himself... is there any `sys.path` insertions?

Comment: Is there any way to know that whether it is a local module or not the guy who implemented it ?

Comment: before the `import dataAnalysis as DV` is there anything like `sys.path.insert()` ?

Answer (score 0):

Go to console or terminal and run command `pip install dataAnalysis`. If permission denied, then make sure you have enough privilege to install a package.

**Update**:
In my opinion pip package [DataAnalysis](https://pypi.org/project/DataAnalysis/) is a library that can be used for pre-processing a csv file. As per your given code, it looks like adding a graph so may be it could be a local package. Check dataAnalysis folder in your project with `__init__.py` file inside.

Comment: @Sambit kindly have a look at my updated answer. I have clearly mentioned about if a package is local or not. You can search Official PyPi  website (https://pypi.org/) to search a module name if it exists or not. If it doesn't exist it means that package was built locally.